# Reduce sum and subtract nested array

Tags: javascript

i have a problem with reduce.

I want to add the rest of the arrays from the first array in the array.
array = [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]
the order to come is:  (a-b)+(c-d)+(e-f), but my code not work :((

my code is:

```js
const sumAndSubtract = (numberInNestedArray) => {
  return numberInNestedArray.reduce((acc, cur, ind, arr) => {
    const firstSubtract = arr[0][0] - arr[0][1];
    const otherSubtract = acc[ind] - cur[ind];
    console.log(firstSubtract);
    console.log(otherSubtract);
    return firstSubtract + otherSubtract;
  })
}



console.log(sumAndSubtract([
  [10, 0],
  [5, 7],
  [6, 9]
]))
```

expect result: 10 + (-2)+(-3)

Comment: You don't have an initial value for your `reduce` so it will take the first value of the array for the first iteration but the sum for the second iteration.

Comment: Also, `cur[ind]` is wrong - `cur` is always going to be an array with two values but `ind` is in the range 0-2 (or more with more elements).

Comment: `15 + (-2)+(-3)`? Shouldn't it be `(10-0)+(5-7)+(6-9) = 5`?

Comment: Yes my, mistake. Should be (10-0)+(5-7)+(6-9) = 5

Comment: What are you trying to do with firstSubtract? and what is acc[ind] ? acc is a number

Comment: `numberInNestedArray.reduce((acc, arr)=> { return acc + (arr[0] - arr[1]) }, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `reduce` as follows, where `a` is the accumulating sum, and `b` and `c` are the atomic values retrieved from each pair:

```js
let result = [[10, 0], [5, 7], [6, 9]].reduce((a, [b, c]) => a+b-c, 0);
console.log(result);
```

In your attempt, the following is not right:

- The expression `arr[0][0] - arr[0][1]`. This only looks at the first pair in the array, and does so in each iteration. Instead, you should be doing `cur[0] - cur[1]`.
- The expression  `acc[ind] - cur[ind]`: `ind` is the index in the outer array, which takes values 0, 1 and 2 for the example input. `acc[ind]` is a pair, not a number and `cur[ind]` will at some point be an out of range reference, as `cur` only has two values.
- The call to `reduce` should get the initial value argument, because without it, the first pair will be the initial value of `acc`, which you don't want: you want a *number*. So pass 0 as initial value argument to `reduce`.
- What you call `otherSubtract` is already given as `acc`, so you actually don't need this variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could map the subtractions and add the values later.

```js
const
    add = (a, b) => a + b,
    subtract = (a, b) => a - b,
    sumAndSubtract = array => array
        .map(a => a.reduce(subtract))
        .reduce(add);


console.log(sumAndSubtract([[10, 0], [5, 7], [6, 9]]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way to do it will be:

```
numberInNestedArray.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + (cur[0] - cur[1]), 0)
```